# JackMidi.eventWrite - time parameter

Tags: java, jna, midi, jack

I'm using this library: https://github.com/jaudiolibs/jnajack

I created a simple project to reproduce my issue: https://github.com/sc3sc3/MidiJnaJackTest

I have a JackPort outputPort running and appears in QjackCtl in 'Output Ports'.

In QjackCtl this outputPort is connected to GMIDImonitor, to observe Midi traffic.
I send MidiMessages to GMIDImonitor via method below.
I can't figure out the value of the *time* parameter.
When I set `time = jackClient.getFrameTime()` then the message does not arrive in GMIDImonitor.
When I set it to for example to 300 then one message is being sent eternally in a loop.

Any help? Thanks

```
public void processMidiMessage(ShortMessage shortMessage) {
    System.out.println("processMidiMessage: " + shortMessage + ", on port: " + this.outputPort.getName());
    try {
        JackMidi.clearBuffer(this.outputPort);
    } catch (JackException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        int time = 300;
        JackMidi.eventWrite(this.outputPort, time, shortMessage.getMessage(), shortMessage.getLength());
    } catch (JackException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like `time` is an offset so `getFrameTime()` is a rather large number and "never arrives" may mean a very long time in the future.  The [native DLL](https://jackaudio.org/api/group__MIDIAPI.html#gaa25503c07ac3c2ed62d79be9c25d42ed) talks about sending things in order.  Have you tried using `0` or `1`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jack MIDI client seems to send MIDI messages repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28122968/jack-midi-client-seems-to-send-midi-messages-repeatedly)

Comment: @DanielWiddis thank you for taking the time. I have tried 0 and 1, these values also result in a loop. I'll look at the link you mention.

Comment: There is something fundamental I'm not understanding. I've created a simple project https://github.com/sc3sc3/MidiJnaJackTest . I think the midiMessage should be processed on the ProcessCallBack, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: Solved the issue by adding messages to a queue and processing the queue in the ProcessCallBack. 0 is a valid value for time